# Print an array of empty interfaces in golang?

Tags: pointers, go

I have a struct with a field of the form `field []interface{}`. If I print the field, I get back a pointer reference. If I try to dereference the field, I get an error "invalid indirect".

The code is below:

```
type MyType struct {
   field []interface{}
}
myType := //create a MyType. Field is just an array of numbers
println(myType.field) // prints a pointer reference, ex: [1/1]0xc420269aa0
println(*(myType.field)) // doesn't compile
```

How do I print the values in `myType.field`?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @KerrekSB read the title

Comment: Title fragment? Meaning guess?

Comment: Meaning read. It prints an array reference. Expected result is to print values

Comment: Don't use the internal print/println functions. Use the `fmt` package and format the output however you want.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to loop through the array, or even better, use `fmt.Println`.

```
func dump(items []interface{}) {
 for i := 0; i < len(items); i++ {
    fmt.Println(items[i])
   }
}
// OR
fmt.Println(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Array interfaces can be printed as follows

```golang
questionSet := []interface{}{} 

// ... code to fillup the question set

fmt.Printf("%t", questionSet)
```

and here is the result

```golang
[%!t(*domain.Question=&{First Economics question 3 
[{Economics option 1 for student false} 
{Economics option 2 for student false} 
{Economics option 3 for student true} 
{Economics option 4 for student false}] 
[{Economics first topic} {Economics second topic}]}) 

%!t(*domain.Question=&{second Question 4 
[{Qs2 Option 1 for student false} 
{Qs2 Option 2 for student false} 
{Qs2 Option 3 for student false} 
{Qs2 Option 4 for student false}] 
[{third topic} {fourth topic}]})]
```

The output here is not very pretty but at least you can see the result and extract your relevant information for further process.

In the above result `domain.Question` is a struct and here is the complete struct for your reference. Hope this will help you to understand better.

```golang
type Question struct {
    Questions string            `json:"questions,omitempty" bson:"questions"`
    Marks     string            `json:"marks,omitempty" bson:"marks"`
    Options   []QuestionOptions `json:"options,omitempty" bson:"options"`
    Topics    []QuestionTopic   `json:"topics,omitempty" bson:"topics"`
}

type QuestionOptions struct {
    Option  string `json:"option" bson:"option"`
    Correct bool   `json:"correct" bson:"correct"`
}

type QuestionTopic struct {
    Topic string `json:"topic" bson:"topic"`
}
```

Consider that the verb `%t` is designed to print boolean (see the doc overview at https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/), as such, while using it to dump the content of a value works as of today, it is not the behavior intended by go authors, and as such, this behavior might change in the future.

Peace,

Comment: take care that `%t` is to print `the word true or false` for a boolean. You can see you are missusing it as the verb gets printed in the output in the form of `%!t`, It would not if it were correctly used. The proper verb to dump a value is `%#v`. ref https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

Comment: When I `%#v` use I get the references like this  `[]interface {}{(*domain.Question)(0xc00030e140), (*domain.Question)(0xc00030e1e0)}` which is not the purpose of the original question. Yes, `%t` is used for `boolean` but it's also printing the interface array values which is useful for display purpose. It keeps away from writing loop when I just want to check result for temporary purpose.

Comment: neat. though it has to be mentionned that you are voluntarely missusing this verb and this is subject to change in future.

Comment: Yep, I think you are correct. I will edit my answer. Thank you for correcting me @mh-cbon

Comment: Thanks a lot mh-cbon. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

another way you could use

https://play.golang.org/p/4lLQ4Gb2S0m

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(dump(new(bool)))
    fmt.Println(dump([]interface{}{new(bool), new(string)}))
}

func dump(x interface{}) string {
    json, err := json.MarshalIndent(x, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return string(json)
}
// Outputs:
// false
// [
//   false,
//   ""
// ]
```